# JavaScript proxy objects don't work

Tags: javascript, firefox

JavaScript proxy objects in Firefox don't seem to work on web audio objects.

For example:

```
audio = new AudioContext();
s = audio.createOscillator();
s0 = new Proxy (s, {});
s0.connect(audio.destination);
s0.start();
```

The above code should forward all operations on s0 to s. However, I get errors like:

> "TypeError: 'start' called on an object that does not implement interface OscillatorNode."

I've searched for any info on this, but have not found anything relevant. Is this a known bug / limitation? Are these objects not proxiable for some definate reason?

Thanks for any info on this.

-- Rich

Comment: `s0` is a standard exotic object. `OscillatorNode`s are not standard objects. When you call `connect`, you are passing `s0` as the `this` value. So it fails. Why are you using a proxy, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, when you call a method on a proxy, the method will receive the proxy as the `this` value, not the underlying object.

```
function Constructor() {}
Constructor.prototype.method = function() {
  return this;
};
var obj = new Constructor(),
    proxy = new Proxy(obj, {});
obj.method(); // obj
proxy.method(); // proxy
```

In this case, your `AudioContext` instance is a non-standard object, so the implementation can have implementation defined internal data stored on it, which can be used to know whether it's an `AudioContext` or not. Since proxy objects only redirect essential internal methods, it can be detected that it's not an `AudioContext` instance.

If you really need to use a proxy wrapper, you can try adding a `get` trap:

```
var audio = new AudioContext(),
    s = audio.createOscillator();
s0 = new Proxy (s, {
  get: function(target, property, receiver) {
    var val = target[property];
    if(typeof val !== 'function') return val;
    return function(...args) {
      var thisVal = this === receiver ? target : this; /* Unwrap the proxy */
      return Reflect.apply(val, thisVal, args);
    }
  }
});
s0.connect(audio.destination);
s0.start();
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is arrange things such that when I set a 3d panner position on a panner object (or on the listener - sort of a special case of a panner), the position is saved somewhere so I can query it later. Currently, you can  set the position of audioContext.listener or a 3d panner, but you can't query it.

I thought a proxy object would be a good way to override the setPosition method, but perhaps I want to simply inherrit from a panner or listener node and  override setPosition, and add my own getPosition methods, respectively.

How would one do this?

-- Rich

Comment: I don't know these audio APIs, but it seems you are talking about `PannerNode.prototype.setPosition`. Since it's inherited, you could try `var _setPosition = panner.setPosition; panner.setPosition = function() { /* ... */ return _setPosition.apply(this, arguments); }`